# What number of tables in a SQL database would be considered too much?

Tags: sql, performance

I joined a project that has close to 800 tables in a database. There is considerable denormalization present.

Is there a number of tables in a database/project that would be considered detrimental to the overall performance or maintainability?

In other words, should I (we) be worried about that number, or is it perfectly fine, and the issue can be shrugged off?

Comment: No, there is no such number. Sometimes 10 is too much, sometimes 800 is not enough

Comment: you should focus on the question if every table is needed, or maybe some of them can/should be merged or deleted, its more effective than just counting them. There are cases where tables present different instances, which are all important, then its ok to have as much as you need, so decision if to worry or not is on you after analysis.

Comment: What is the database for? It's normal to use denormalized tables in reporting databases and star schemas. It's probably *not* normal if denormalization was used instead of proper indexing, or using techniques like indexed views, columnstore tables, or separate reporting databases.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The database is used for an internal application that has a relatively small number of users. I have no say in creating/merging the tables and so I believe that the trend will continue. While there are reports being made, the meat and potatoes of the application is entering new data about customers. The app is a bit sluggish, that's why I was worried

Comment: *"No, there is no such number. Sometimes 10 is too much, sometimes 800 is not enough "* @a_horse_with_no_name to add to his comment ... More precieze would might very possibly be very OS / Disk partitioning system depended as in some (if not all) databases systems databases/tables are implemented as files in a directory..  Know fact alot off files in one directory will not scale well when the OS needs to find / open the file.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Oracle, SQL Server use a single file for multiple tables (and I think MySQL's InnoDB as well). The only DBMS I know that uses multiple files per table is Postgres - but I have never heard any problems regarding that. Modern filesystems can copy quite well with that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name *"Oracle, SQL Server use a single file for multiple tables (and I think MySQL's InnoDB as well)."* i said some (if not all), the if not all part shouldn't be read that literal.. But MySQL innoDB also can run as a single file per table. *"Modern filesystems can copy quite well with that."* even they slow down when having alot off files in one directory the main problem is **finding** a file asssuming no (disk) caching here..Also i think most database systems are caching the table handles as well so thery not have to reopen a file all times i know MySQL does.